# Изменение ячейки в БД

Tags: php

Доброго времени суток, пишу диплом и вот код одного из файлов проекта
здесь происходит формирование ЭЦП платежной системы, проверки подлинности и в случае успешной оплаты должен статус в моей бд изменяться с 0 на 1.
Оплата проходит успешно, а статус с 0 никак не меняется.
Файл db.php содержит настройки подключения к бд и подключается в файлу rb.php(RedBean).
Подскажите где ошибка, мучаюсь 4-ый день

```
<?php

if(empty($_POST)){
    die;
}

require_once __DIR__ . '/inc/db.php';

$key = 'dLyXYTDaB8d7Dqfa';
$ik_id = '5adb24a23d1eaf364b8b4569';
$dataSet = $_POST;

unset($dataSet['ik_sign']);
ksort($dataSet, SORT_STRING);
array_push($dataSet, $key);
$signString = implode(':', $dataSet);
$sign = base64_encode(md5($signString, true));
return $sign;

$order = R::load('orders', (int)$dataSet['ik_pm_no']);
if(!$order) die;

if($dataSet['ik_co_id'] != $ik_id || $dataSet['ik_inv_st'] != 'success' || $dataSet['ik_am'] != $order->price || $sign != $_POST['ik_sign']){
    die;
}

$order->status = '1';
R::store($order);
?>

<?php
```

Код взаимодействия с бд

```
require_once 'rb.php';

$db = [
    'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=payment;charset=utf8',
    'user' => 'payment',
    'pass' => '****',
];

R::setup($db['dsn'], $db['user'], $db['pass']);
R::freeze(true);
```

Comment: А где код взаимодействующий с БД? Да и вообще что-то у вас в коде происходит не логичное - после `return $sign;` код прекращает выполнение, поэтому всё что ниже указанной строки просто не имеет смысла.

Comment: Добавил код бд и удалил return, удаление не помогло, есть еще какие-то идеи?

Comment: Используйте отладку, чтобы убедиться в работоспособности данного скрипта.

Comment: так можно на любой вопрос ответить :(

Answer (score 0):

Возможно ошибка ещё на этапе извлечения данных из таблицы

```
   $order = R::load('orders', (int)$dataSet['ik_pm_no']);
   if(!$order) die('ERROR');
```